# Android, how to populate a CharSequence array dynamically (not initializing?)

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, charsequence

How do I change something like this:

```
CharSequence cs[] = { "foo", "bar" };
```

to:

```
CharSequence cs[];

cs.add("foo"); // this is wrong...
cs.add("bar"); // this is wrong...
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use a List object to manage items and when you have all the elements then convert to a CharSequence. Something like this:

```
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

listItems.add("Item1");
listItems.add("Item2");
listItems.add("Item3");

final CharSequence[] charSequenceItems = listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);
```

Comment: should be listItems.add("Item1");

Comment: In Kotlin: val listItems: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

        listItems.add("Item1")
        listItems.add("Item2")
        listItems.add("Item3")

        val charSequenceItems = listItems.toTypedArray<CharSequence>()

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there. You need to allocate space for the entries, which is automatically done for you in the initializing case above.

```
CharSequence cs[];

cs = new String[2];

cs[0] = "foo"; 
cs[1] = "bar";
```

Actually CharSequence is an Interface and can thus not directly be created, but String as one of its implementations can.

Comment: This won't compile, Arrays don't have `add` method.

Comment: Sorry, but, on "cs.add(...)", I get: "Cannot invoke add(String) on the array type CharSequence[]"...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `List`, to have a dynamic number of members in the array(list :)):

```
List<CharSequence>  cs = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

cs.add("foo"); 
cs.add("bar");
```

If you want to use array, you can do:

```
CharSequence cs[];

cs = new String[2];

cs[0] = "foo"; 
cs[1] = "bar";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be dynamical, you should think in an another structure and then convert it to a CharSequence when you need. Alternatively, [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615667/how-to-add-data-in-charsequence-dynamically-in-java) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ArrayList instead of raw arrays since need to add items dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN**

First, convert the ArrayList to a regular, mutable list.
Then, manually create the Array using the [Array constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays). Make sure that your init function generates a data type that fits the Array (ex. don't put an int in a CharSequence arrray).

```
val exampleArray: ArrayList<String> arrayListOf("test1", "test2", "test3")
val exampleList = exampleArray.toList()
val exampleItems: Array<CharSequence?>? = exampleList?.size?.let { it1 -> Array(it1,{ i -> exampleArray?.get(i) }) }
```